# Memory leak issue in Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, memory-leaks, universal-image-loader, linkedhashmap, eclipse-memory-analyzer

By analyzing with MAT

```
One instance of "com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader" loaded by
"dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x414d28b8" occupies 3,866,808 (26.42%) bytes. 
The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.LinkedHashMap" loaded by "<system class loader>".
```

Here is the screenshot of `dominator_tree`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ImageLoader is not an Universal ImageLoader. Android is providing AQuery for Image Loading.

You will find aQuery jar file from below link:

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

```
private AQuery androidAQuery;
androidAQuery = new AQuery(getActivity());

androidAQuery.id(your imageview).image(your image value, true, true,default icon(optional));
```